# Magento Admin - Reorder - New Increment ID

Tags: magento1.9.3, reorder, increment-id

In magento 1.9.x if i click in "reorder" in an order page he duplicate the increment_id of original order and add "-1" in the end.

ex:
order-> increment_id = 12345

reorder-> increment_id = 12345-1

where i can found this function? 
there is a way to change this function? because i need to create new increment_id

ex:
order-> increment_id = 12345

reorder-> increment_id = 12346

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php**

Check following method:

```
public function createOrder()
{
```

Check following code:

```
if ($oldOrder->getId()) {
    $originalId = $oldOrder->getOriginalIncrementId();
    if (!$originalId) {
        $originalId = $oldOrder->getIncrementId();
    }
    $orderData = array(
        'original_increment_id'     => $originalId,
        'relation_parent_id'        => $oldOrder->getId(),
        'relation_parent_real_id'   => $oldOrder->getIncrementId(),
        'edit_increment'            => $oldOrder->getEditIncrement()+1,
        'increment_id'              => $originalId.'-'.($oldOrder->getEditIncrement()+1)
    );
    $quote->setReservedOrderId($orderData['increment_id']);
    $service->setOrderData($orderData);

    $oldOrder->cancel();
}
```

Comment out following two line:

```
//$quote->setReservedOrderId($orderData['increment_id']);
//$service->setOrderData($orderData);
```

**NB: Don't modify core code. Use overwrite for modification.**